# Legacy OpenGL Textures not working correctly

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I am usign legacy openGL. I am drawing multiple objects in a scene. I want the sphere that is being drawn to be textured but all other objects to be solid colours. However, if I try to disable the texture after drawing the sphere, everything else is black.

This is the code where I create the texture

```
    glGenTextures(1, &textures);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, image->Width(), image->Height(), 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->imageField());
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

This is where i draw the sphere:

```
id Objects::sphere(float xPos, float yPos, float zPos){
    const int NR_PHI = 20;
    const int NR_THETA = 20;

    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);

  for(int longitude = 0; longitude < NR_PHI; longitude++)
    for(int latitude = 0; latitude < NR_THETA; latitude++){
      float d_phi   = 2*M_PI/NR_PHI;
      float d_theta = M_PI/NR_THETA; 
      glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures);
      double x, y, z;

      x = cos(longitude*d_phi)*sin(latitude*d_theta) + xPos;
      y = sin(longitude*d_phi)*sin(latitude*d_theta) + yPos;
      z = cos(latitude*d_theta) + zPos;
      glNormal3f(x, y, z);
      glTexCoord2f(static_cast<float>(longitude)/NR_PHI, static_cast<float>(latitude)/NR_THETA);
      glVertex3f(x, y, z);
      x = cos((longitude+1)*d_phi)*sin(latitude*d_theta) + xPos;
      y = sin((longitude+1)*d_phi)*sin(latitude*d_theta) + yPos;
      z = cos(latitude*d_theta) + zPos;
      glNormal3f(x, y, z);
      glTexCoord2f(d_phi,0);
      glTexCoord2f(static_cast<float>(longitude+1)/NR_PHI, static_cast<float>(latitude)/NR_THETA);
      glVertex3f(x, y, z);
      x = cos((longitude+1)*d_phi)*sin((latitude+1)*d_theta) + xPos;
      y = sin((longitude+1)*d_phi)*sin((latitude+1)*d_theta) + yPos;
      z = cos((latitude+1)*d_theta) + zPos;
      glNormal3f(x, y, z);
      glTexCoord2f(static_cast<float>(longitude+1)/NR_PHI, static_cast<float>(latitude+1)/NR_THETA);
      glVertex3f(x, y, z);      

      x = cos(longitude*d_phi)*sin(latitude*d_theta) + xPos;
      y = sin(longitude*d_phi)*sin(latitude*d_theta) + yPos;
      z = cos(latitude*d_theta) + zPos; 
      glNormal3f(x, y, z);
      glTexCoord2f(static_cast<float>(longitude)/NR_PHI, static_cast<float>(latitude)/NR_THETA);
      glVertex3f(x, y, z);
      x = cos((longitude+1)*d_phi)*sin((latitude+1)*d_theta) + xPos;
      y = sin((longitude+1)*d_phi)*sin((latitude+1)*d_theta) + yPos;
      z = cos((latitude+1)*d_theta) + zPos;
      glNormal3f(x, y, z);
      glTexCoord2f(static_cast<float>(longitude+1)/NR_PHI, static_cast<float>(latitude+1)/NR_THETA);
      glVertex3f(x, y, z);
      x = cos((longitude)*d_phi)*sin((latitude+1)*d_theta) + xPos;
      y = sin((longitude)*d_phi)*sin((latitude+1)*d_theta) + yPos;
      z = cos((latitude+1)*d_theta) + zPos;
      glNormal3f(x, y, z);
      glTexCoord2f(static_cast<float>(longitude)/NR_PHI, static_cast<float>(latitude+1)/NR_THETA);
      glVertex3f(x, y, z);      

      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);     
      glEnd();
  } 
}
```

Comment: May be the problem is glBindtexture. try to write it out the loop. And I think the normal coord must been clamped between -1 and 1.

Comment: What's up with that double `glTexCoord2f()` call in the middle?

Answer (score 4):

[You can't call `glBindTexture()` inside a `glBegin()`/`glEnd()` pair:](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBegin.xml)

> Only a subset of GL commands can be used between glBegin and glEnd.
>               The commands are
>               glVertex,
>               glColor,
>               glSecondaryColor,
>               glIndex,
>               glNormal,
>               glFogCoord,
>               glTexCoord,
>               glMultiTexCoord,
>               glVertexAttrib,
>               glEvalCoord,
>               glEvalPoint,
>               glArrayElement,
>               glMaterial, and
>               glEdgeFlag.
>               Also,
>               it is acceptable to use
>               glCallList or
>               glCallLists to execute
>               display lists that include only the preceding commands.
>               **If any other GL command is executed between glBegin and glEnd,
>               the error flag is set and the command is ignored.**

So move that `glBindTexture()` call a couple lines up to before `glBegin()`.